# PHP white space

Tags: php, echo

PHP:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="hello">';
include 'world.php';
echo '</div>';
```

There is whitespace between each construct. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the "white space" an issue?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Why does it matter? It's a valid question.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Knowing the reason *why* is the best way to get the most helpful answer.

Comment: I have test your code and see whitespace only before `</div>` and it is normal because you have "\r\n" after `<p></p>`

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php thats not suppose to happen.

Comment: NOTE: I pasted the wrong code when I asked the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: `include` is also a language construct, not a function. References: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#1248 and http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#57. **DO NOT** use parentheses for language constructs.

Comment: Also: do not put `?>` for the last PHP processing block in the file, it's closed automatically by PHP, but it's cleaner, it avoids sending unwanted output to the browser. Reference, section 2.2 from PSR-2: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo '<div id="hello">'; ?><p></p><?php echo '</div>';
```

No whitespace!

There is a line break after `?>`

Comment: PHP eats up a single `\n` newline after each `?>`. So OP assuredly has other whitespace shuffled there. The linebreak after `</p>` however can only be mitigated by removing it.

Comment: Alternatively (maybe too obvious) `<?php echo '<div id="hello"><p></p></div>'; ?>`

Comment: `echo` is not a function, but a language construct. Do not use parentheses to reflect that, even if it works with them. References: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#1138 and http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#140